# S3 TransferAcceleration

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to implement s3 transfer accceleration in an xhr multipart uploader:

My endpoint (with TA) looks like this: `my-upload-dashboard.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com`

The code I'm using looks like this:

```
get signingUrl() {
    let stringToSign = `${this.method}\n\n${(this.contentType || '')}\n\nx-amz-date:${this.date}\n${this.relativeUrl}`;
    stringToSign = encodeURIComponent(stringToSign);
    return `${this.config.signerUrl}?to_sign=${stringToSign}`;
}

get relativeUrl() {
    let folder = this.package_id.toString() + this.user_id.toString() + '-' + this.timestamp
    let bucket = config.s3.bucket + folder;

    return this._relativeUrl || (this._relativeUrl = `/${bucket}/${encodeURIComponent(this.fileName)}${(this.queryParams ? `?${this.queryParams}` : '')}`);
    // return this._relativeUrl || (this._relativeUrl = `${encodeURIComponent(this.fileName)}`);
}
_relativeUrl = null;

get absoluteUrl() {
    return this._absoluteUrl || (this._absoluteUrl = this.combineUrlParts(`${this.config.baseUrl}`, this.relativeUrl));
}
```

However, when I pass in the TA bucket, I get an immediate error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Failed to initiate the multipart upload: [403] Forbidden - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

I'm signing my signature through my backend. It works without TA enabled.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the signature needs to be signed with the original bucketname, while the upload should be sent to the s3-accelerate (Transfer Acceleration) bucket name

Comment: That is true for Signature Version 2, which is what you are using (based on your `stringToSign`). Signature Version 4 expects you to use the full endpoint hostname as the signed host header, which would be the accelerate endpoint if using acceleration for the transfer.  Sig V4 works in all regions, while V2 only works on buckets in S3 regions launched before 2014.

Comment: Be sure you're carefully validating that string to sign, by the way.  The way you are doing this, a malicious user could potentially exploit your signing code to sign requests for other methods (delete?) or your other buckets.  It's safest to pass only the essential parameters to the back-end, separately, and build your string to sign on the server including the bucket name and method, rather than trusting the client.